# Force HTTP to HTTPS except one page accessed via HTTP

Tags: htaccess, redirects, https, http

I'm trying to redirect a website to HTTPS, but there is one URL that needs to be accessed via HTTP. Currently I just have this in `.htaccess`:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com
```

I need to have the following URL available through HTTP:

```
http://example.com/asistente/
```

It is an assistant page separate from the website, that in labor is accessed via QR code.

How can I force HTTPS for everything except that one page listed above?

Comment: Redirecting to HTTPS shouldn't keep a QR code from working.  Users that scan the code would just get redirected to the page using HTTPS.  What is the problem with that?

Comment: Is the directive you posted intended to redirect HTTP to HTTPS? Do HTTP requests have a different document root to HTTPS requests?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with *Stephen*'s comment: HTTPS will not break the QR code itself.
There might be some hosting reasons to keep your QR-encoded URL untouched. I guess you may want to avoid any HTTPS issue (old browsers, etc.) with this URL (and its children).

Here are Apache directives which, in an `.htaccess` file, will redirect all requests to HTTPS, except `http://(www.)example.com/asistente` and its children URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/asistente($|/)
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "as suggested by _MrWhite_" - I wasn't referring to the QR code... I was just querying the OP's use of `Redirect` in their "current" `.htaccess` file - since ordinarily, that would have resulted in a (malformed) redirect loop, yet we are led to assume that it is working as intended - which is puzzling.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry @MrWhite